# How to spread this array object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread

I have the following object:

```js
const info = [{ name: 'John', address: 'america', gender: 'Male', job: 'SE' }];
```

And I need to spread this array object and get this as

```
form:{
   name:"John",
   address:"america",
   gender:"Male",
   job:"SE"
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what about other objects of the array?

Comment: const formJson = {form: info[0]}
console.log(formJson)

Comment: @souravsatyam - There is no JSON in the question or your answer, so that's an odd identifier name. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need spread for that unless you want to make a shallow copy of the object. Instead, just use the object that's in the array:

```
const form = info[0];
```

or as a property on an object:

```
const obj = {form: info[0]};
```

At that point, `form`/`obj.form` and `info[0]` are both pointing to the same object.

If you *do* want to make a shallow copy, then spread is useful:

```
const form = {...info[0]};
```

or

```
const obj = {form: {...info[0]}};
```

There, `form`/`obj.form` points to a new object that has a copy of `info[0]`'s properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the array and take the wanted property as target.

```js
const
    info = [{ "name": "John", "address": "america", "gender": "Male", "job": "SE" }],
    result = {};

[{ ...result.form }] = info;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what we have another record too.
Like
info = [{ "name": "John", "address": "america", "gender": "Male", "job": "SE" },{ "name": "John", "address": "america", "gender": "Male", "job": "SE" }],

Comment: what result do you expect from this?